# Expressing any map $T: K^n \rightarrow K^m$ in the form $T(v) = (f_1(v),...,f_m(v))^t$ where the $f_i$ are linear forms on $K^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering a function $T: K^n \rightarrow K^m$ such that 
$T(v) = (f_1(v),...,f_m(v))^t$ where the $f_i$ are linear forms on $K^n$, Then how can I show that any arbitrary map from  $T: K^n \rightarrow K^m$ can be expressed in this manner.

I would think that I have to consider the effect of $T$ on the standard basis elements of $K^n$ but I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we think of elements of $K^n$ as column vectors. Given $T$ there exists a unique matrix $A \in M_{m \times n}(K)$ such that $T(v) = Av$. Written explicitly, we have

$$ T \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{mn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} $$

where

$$v = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} \in K^n. $$

Now consider the linear forms

$$ f_i \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} = a_{i1} x_1 + \dots + a_{in} x_n.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the compositions of the projections $K^m\to K$ with $T$.